# Renderizar Html

Tags: c#, api, .net-6.0

Trabajo con VS 2022, PdfSharpCore, Razor Engine, Net 6, C#, aplicación de consola

Deseo renderizar un archivo html desde el backend para poder crear un pdf, tengo el siguiente código.

```
using CrearPDF;
using PdfSharpCore.Drawing;
using PdfSharpCore.Drawing.Layout;
using PdfSharpCore.Pdf;
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


var pathSemanal = Path.Combine("D:/CrearPDF/Html/", "ReporteSemanal.html");

//HTML Factura
string readTextFactura = File.ReadAllText(pathSemanal);
var template = readTextFactura;
var model = new Model();

var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "Key", null, model);

PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// Agregar una página al documento
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Configurar la fuente y formato
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 12, XFontStyle.Regular);
//XStringFormat format = XStringFormat.TopLeft;
XRect rect = new XRect(50, 50, page.Width - 100, page.Height - 100);

// Renderizar el contenido HTML en el PDF
XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
tf.DrawString(result, font, XBrushes.Black, rect);

// Ruta de salida del archivo PDF
string rutaPdf = "D:/ImagenReporte/informe.pdf"; // Reemplaza con la ruta deseada para el PDF

// Guardar el documento PDF en la ruta especificada
document.Save(rutaPdf);

// Cerrar el documento
document. Close();
```

En la siguiente linea

```
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "Key", null, model);
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'

Al parecer la ruta que tengo esta bien, no se a que se debe este error, no se como solucionar ese error.

Comment: ¿Has probado a importar ese nuget en el proyecto?